# Bind data of interface properties only

Tags: c#, entity-framework, data-binding

I am new in all the Entity Framework models and the data bindings.
I created an interface and generated a model class from my `Candidate` table in the db.

```
public interface ICandidate
{
    String ID { get; set; }
    string Name { get; set; }
    string Mail { get; set; }
}
```

i created a partial class to the generated `Candidate` model so i will be able to implement the `ICandidate` interface without changing any generated code.

```
public partial class Candidates : ICandidate
{
    string ICandidate.ID
    {
        get { return this.PK; }
        set { _PK = value; }
    }
    string ICandidate.Name
    {
        get{ return this._Name; }
        set { _Name = value; }
    }
    string ICandidate.Mail
    {
        get { return this._Email; }
        set { this._Email = value; }
    }
}
```

Of course, the generated class has more properties than the interface has (Like IsDeleted field that is not necessary for the interface).

I want to display in a `DataGridView` all the candidates from the db. But I want that only the interface's properties will be shown as columns in the `DataGridView`.

1. Is there a way bind only the interface's properties the the DataGridView?
2. In my DB there is a table called Candidate_To_Company with these columns:
   PK, Candidate_FK, Company_FK, Insertion_Date
   I would like to bind this table to DataGridView. but instead of displaying Candidate_FK i would like to display the candidate name from ICandidate. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way bind only the interface's properties the the DataGridView?

Couple of options:

1. Explicitly set up the columns in the `DataGridView` rather than having them auto-generated.  In my experience I usually start with auto-generated columns and then find some reason why I need to explicitly set up the columns (formatting, order, etc.)
2. Create a model class that only has those properties and convert from your entity class to that model either manually or using a tool like [AutoMapper](http://automapper.org/).

> In my DB there is a table called Candidate_To_Company ... i would like to display the candidate name from ICandidate. Is this possible?

Since you have columns other than the foreign keys, EF will NOT map that as a many-to-many relationship and set up the navigation properties for you since the PK you added (which in unnecessary IMHO) and the `InsertDate` would be unavailable in your model.

Again, a few options:

1. If you created a separate model for question 1, set up the navigation properties in your model and map from the entity model to the view model going through the intermediate table:

   `Company.Candidates = efCompany.Candidate_to_Companies.Select(cc=>cc.Candidate).ToList();`
2. Figure out how to tell the model to use the intermediate table as a many-to-many intermediate table instead of its own entity. This assumes the DB populates those columns automatically via triggers and/or IDENTITY columns so there's no need to have them in the entity model.
3. Remove the PK and InsertionDate columns, generate your model, and then add the extra columns.  This is actually a bit hackish and would likely give you problems if you ever needed to regenerate the model.  I'd only do this as an experiment to see how to do #2.

Answer (score 0):

Does the DataGrid neeed to be bound to an interface? Is the reason for the interface to have the DataGrid only display the data you want?..

What you could do is have the DataGrid bind to a DataTable (populated via SqlDataAdapter). From there, you can specify which database columns to bind, and rename the DataGrid's column header however you want.

See http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/362436/Data-binding-in-WPF-DataGrid-control